# Java / Database-Query: null or Excpetion?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, null

I have a design question. In a small java application we have some classes which are used to access the (mysql) database. There exists the following method:

```
public Integer getPvpBotId(int userId);
```

It returns the `BotId` of the PvpBot of the given user. Not every user has a PvpBot. And a Bot itself is a relatively big object, so i dont like to load the full object and return it, just the id.

Unless the PvpBot exists, should i return `null`? (which i do currently with the Integer instead of int)

Or should i throw an exception?

I ask this, because i like to produce code which is as clean as possible.

regards

Kevin

Comment: Well it depends on what suits your application and what you are going to do with the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in your question, not all users will have a bot, thus it is to be *expected* to encounter some null values.

I think that in this case, you could return `null`, since not finding a bot does not seem to be an *exceptional* case.

It is important though that you state what you return an why, so as to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, raising exception involves extra effort (on JVM part) so I would say return a value to indicate missing record - i.e. when ID does not exist, and raise an exception if your DB connection was down at the time

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if at the point of where the `getPvpBotId(int userId)` is called the component is heavily dependent on the `BotId` e.g. it's a module for handling `PvpBot` related stuff and/or the `BotId` is expected, you'd throw an exception.

If at the point where the `BotId` is retrieved the `PvpBot` related data only is a part of the component (e.g. displaying additional information/functionality if the user has a `PvpBot` attached.) then the function should return `null` instead of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) type of the [guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) .
It is designed specifically for your scenario. Instead of returning null, you would return Optional.absent(), thus signaling the user of your method the absence of your Bot in a well typed manner and avoiding possible null pointers.

Your code would look like this:

```
public Optional<Integer> getPvpBotId(int userId) {
  if (userHasBot()) { // insert your routine here
    return Optional.of(botid);
  }
  else {
    return Optional.absent();
  }
 }
```

with the caller being able to distinguish:

```
 if (getPvpBotId(12).isPresent()) {
   Integer botId = getPvpBotId(12).get();
 }
 else {
   // Not Bot is present...
 }
```